# backup files that older then 3 day

Tags: find

how to move files that start as:
 **DRR_O_sql.**

and that older then 3 days to other directory as /home/backup

example

```
 DRR_O_sql.35435
 DRR_O_sql.4534534
 DRR_O_sql.54232
 DRR_O_sql.4.efdedwe
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
find /some/path -name DRR_O_sql\* -mtime +3 -type f -exec mv "{}" /home/backup \;
```

/some/path is your source.

Note that this will not preserve directory structures.

Answer (score 0):

Replace directory "/tmp/SOURCE" in the example below, and dont forget to test properly, especially think of duplicate file names.

```
find /tmp/SOURCE -type f -name DRR_O_sql\* -atime +4 -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' cp --preserve '{}' /home/backup
```

Comment: I need to move the file so I need to use the mv command , so can you change the code according to that